# How to add Copy to clipboard functionality in ExtJs?

Tags: javascript, extjs

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to add Copy to clipboard functionality in ExtJs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5164001/how-to-add-copy-to-clipboard-functionality-in-extjs)

How to add Copy to clipboard functionality in ExtJs?
It's working fine with IE browser but not Firefox, What else has to be altered to make it work in FF browser.

Code::

```
function selectCopy(txt,txtId)
{

Ext.getCmp(txtId).focus();
Ext.getCmp(txtId).selectText();

var s = document.getElementById(txtId).value;

var div = document.createElement('div');
div.innerText = '"' + s + '"';
document.body.appendChild(div);

if (window.clipboardData  && clipboardData.setData){
     window.clipboardData.setData('text', s);}
else
     return (s);
```

Comment: This is duplicate question of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5164001/how-to-add-copy-to-clipboard-functionality-in-extjs

Comment: Please don't ask the same question twice.

Answer (score -1):

As far as I know you cant set clipboard in firefox